# Issue in notifying RecyclerView Adapter while is in Scrolling mode

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I have list of items in Recyclerview.
There is one Switch button in app for specific type of data.

On Switch Click, I am calling particular service and new data being set in recyclerview.

This above things works fine, but when I do the same after scrolling recyclerview or when my recyclerview is in scrolling mode getting below error :

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder{9dea1e position=24 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 no parent} androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally it's resolved using below steps.

Must have to clear previous data.

Must have to notify adapter.

If pagination is used, have to store nesessary values to default.

Done something as below before new api call:

```
        if (mAlList != null) {
            mAlList.clear()
        }

        if(mAdapterList!=null)
        {
            mAdapterList!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        isScrolling=false
        page = 1
        limit = 20
        isLoadMore = false
```

Answer (score -1):

```
IndexOutOfBoundsException:
```

For this, You Need to add onClickListener using the interface , don't use it in onBindViewHolder as it will create exception like this. 
thanks